# How to filter() out NaN, null, 0, false in an array (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, boolean, nan

I was asked to filter out **NaN, null, 0, false** in an **array**.

Luckily I have answered the question.

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  function filterer(arr) {
     return arr > 0|| isNaN(arr) === true;
  }
  arr = arr.filter(filterer);
  return arr;
}

//example input
bouncer([0, 1, 2, 3, 'ate', '', false]); //output [1, 2, 3, 'ate']
```

but the thing is I really don't know how I came up with the answer or rather I don't know how it works. Specially on **arr > 0** how did the filter know that arr is alread on arr[1], arr[2], etc.. without using a loop to iterate in all array.

or can simply just explain on how to code works. [I've tried to explain it clearly ---]

Comment: Your code is wrong. It fails for values like `-1`... Try `arr.filter(function(item) {return !!item;})`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol why not `[0, 1, 2, 3, 'ate', '', false].filter(Boolean)` ?

Comment: yeah Boolean filter is the best unless you want to keep undefined

Comment: If you remove `isNaN` then @MattBurland `ate` will also remove output will be `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: @Manwal: Fair point, I missed `ate` in there.

Comment: Hmmm i have explained in my answer as compilation of filter. Its good to watch filtering array @Fhrey.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thanks for pointing that out. Will try to figure out how your code works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for `Array.filter`. Notice in particular the arguments to the callback:

> Function to test each element of the array. Invoked with arguments (element, index, array). Return true to keep the element, false otherwise.

So in your case `arr` is the element (and poorly named, hence your confusion). Filter loops through your array and for every item it calls you callback passing in the element at the current position as `arr`.

As others have pointed out in the comments, the logic of your filter callback is actually flawed for negative values, but that may not be an issue if you know that your array will never contain negative values (but that can be a dangerous thing to assume).

And, of course, internally, this is looping through your array. You can't filter your (unsorted) array without touching each element in the array. Look at the polyfil in the link to get an idea of how it *might* work (might because this is an implementation detail that may differ with different javascript engines, but will no doubt involve a loop somewhere), it loops through your array, calls the callback (note the arguments) and if the callback returns true, it gets pushed onto a results array.

Comment: Thanks! that's what I wanted to know. **internally, this is looping through your array** Thank you very much! and I'll try improving my naming of the variables! :)

Answer (score 79):

If you were asked to filter out `NaN`, `null`, `0`, `false` in an array, then your solutions doesn't really work.

Your input of:

```
bouncer([0, 1, 2, 3, 'ate', '', false, NaN]);
```

Will get the output of:

```
[1, 2, 3, 'ate', NaN]
```

To filter out all 'falsy' values you can simply use `Boolean`:

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  return arr.filter(Boolean);
}

bouncer([0, 1, 2, 3, 'ate', '', false, NaN]);
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 'ate']
```

---

Since the `Boolean` constructor is also a function, it returns either `true` for ‘truthy’ argument or `false` for ‘falsy’ argument. If the value is omitted or is `0`, `-0`, `null`, `false`, `NaN`, `undefined`, or the empty string (`""`), the object has the value of false. All other values, including any object or the string `"false"`, create an object with an initial value of `true`.

Comment: Easily understandable and fast solution.

Answer (score 20):

You can also use an identity function instead of `Boolean`.

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  return arr.filter(x => x);
}
```

Comment: How? Can you please explain

Comment: This answer is better than both the accepted one and the currently most-upvoted one.

Comment: @messi Think of it as `arr.filter(x => !!x)` and it works because `!!NaN` is false

Answer (score 7):

I am also working on the Free Code Camp Falsy Bouncer Algorithm.  I have found the simplest way to do it is:

```
function bouncer(arr) {
   return arr.filter(Boolean);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> The [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Since `false`, `null`, `0`, `""`, `undefined` and `NaN` are all **Falsy** values in JavaScript therefore they will return **false** when tested.

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  var array = arr.filter(function(val){
    return val;
  });
  return array;
}
```

Only values which **do not return false** will be added to the **array**.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't be more elegant to base on assumption that all unwanted elements are casted to false when boolean expected, so:

```
function clear (arr){
   var stripped = [];
   for (i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++){
      if (arr[i])
         stripped.push(arr[i]);
   }
   return stripped;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Function to test each element of the array. Invoked with arguments
>   (element, index, array). Return true to keep the element, false
>   otherwise

If you just want explanation. Array [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as name suggest. Remove unwanted element if condition falls wrong (**false**).

(`arr > 0|| isNaN(arr) === true`)

```
0,  false || false  //removed
1,  true || false  
2,  true || false
3,  true || false
'ate', false || true
'',   false|| false  // removed
false  false || false //removed
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, "ate"]
```

Comment: Thanks! after understanding that the filter() method goes through all array elements this example made a excellent way to show on how my filterer function works! great help!

Answer (score 0):

Since i´m a beginner o coding, my logic went to use primitive Boolean´s to compare the item´s
filtered, but this was before I have read the Boolean Object reference, you see is that
like its written there, 
"The value passed as the first parameter is converted to a Boolean value if necessary. If value is omitted or is 0, -0, null, false, NaN, undefined, or the empty string (""), the object has an initial value of false. All other values, including any object or the string "false", create an object with an initial value of true."
So the logic since filter returns the value if it´s true or false, you should return values if
they are true.
Also, I didn´t learn everything about the filter method, for what I have researched, I have got
a bit more of information, that I will try to explain here.´

redefining the method (it already exists, is just for understanding)
the filter method accepts a function called
a predicate, that is a function that receives
a value and returns true or false.

The var results is an empty array where the results will be pushed  with the push method.
The we use a forEach method with this, (this, in this context is applied to the array prototype ,this means that you will have the filter method available on every array that you define, with
the sintax of array.method(args) ins this case array.filter(args))
some resources 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Now we will run an operation in every item on the the array, with the forEach method, now we will apply the predicate function to itch item of the array and if it returns true, will add it to the results.

```
Array.prototype.filter = function(predicate){   
    var results = [];

    this.forEach(function(item) {   
        if (predicate(item)) {
            results.push(item);
        }

    });
};
```

//-------------------------------Correct Solution---------------------------

```
function bouncer (arrToFilter){

    return arrToFilter.filter(Boolean);
}
```

//----------Code without the filter method---------

```
function bouncerNoFilterMethod(arrToFilter){
    var results = [];

    arrToFilter.forEach(function(arrToFilter){
        if(arrToFilter){
            results.push(arrToFilter);
        }
    });

    return  results;    
}

console.log(bouncerNoFilterMethod([7, "ate", "", false, 9]));
console.log(bouncerNoFilterMethod(["a", "b", "c"]));
console.log(bouncerNoFilterMethod([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]));
console.log(bouncerNoFilterMethod([1, null, NaN, 2, undefined]));
console.log(bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]));
console.log(bouncer(["a", "b", "c"]));
console.log(bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]));
console.log(bouncer([1, null, NaN, 2, undefined]));
```

Hope this helps to understand, the method, and the first thing that was not understanding was the part of passing the function, the predicate to the method, if I have mistakes here please suggest corrections.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Boolean is the simplest fix/answer for the "FreeCodeCamp" challenge, however it might be useful to try a couple of things just to get the hang of "why" and "how".

```
function bouncer(arr) {
      return arr.filter(function(val){
        return val;
     });
    }
```

This evaluates everything passing through the filter, using the function(callback) passed in, which returns values. If it doesn't return a value, which null etc won't, it won't be included in the return. At least this method helped me understand why rather than just pass the test.

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified https://stackoverflow.com/a/35327425/3932895 to set everything to zero that has no numerical value

```
function zerofy(x){return (Boolean(x) && !isNaN(x.toString())) ? x : 0 ;}
```

Tested with

```
function clear (arr){
   var stripped = [];
   for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      stripped.push(zerofy(arr[i]));
   }
   return stripped;
}
```

in

```
clear(["written",13,0,-4,"5",true,false,undefined,null,NaN,Math.PI]);
```

results to

[0,13,0,-4,5,0,0,0,0,0,3.141592653589793]

Answer (score -4):

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  // Don't show a false ID to this bouncer.

  function isFalsyBouncer(value){
    if(Boolean(false)||Boolean(null)||Boolean(0)||Boolean("")||Boolean(undefined)||Boolean(NaN)){

    }else{
      return value;
    }
  }
  var filtered=arr.filter(isFalsyBouncer);
  return filtered;
}
```

Comment: This does **not** answer the question in a _useful_ way. **why** do you believe this is the answer? **how** does it work? Simply telling someone to _change their code_ or just _giving someone working code_ without any context or meaning does not help them learn what they did wrong, and is also not as useful for future readers.