# how to remove null, undefined, NaN, 0s, falses and empty string from an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wrote a script to remove any null, undefined, 0, false or empty string value using .splice(), but the code has only removed NaN and 0s.

Here is what I tried:

```
function remove(arr){ // input [NaN, 0, 15, false, -22, '',undefined, 47, null]
    var bin = [];
    for (var i =0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i] == (NaN || 0 || false || "" || undefined || null)){
            arr.splice(arr[i],1);
        }
    }
  console.log(arr); // Expected output [15, -22, 47]
}
```

Comment: `arr = arr.filter(e => e);`

Comment: `arr = arr.filter(Boolean)` is built-in ES5.

Comment: Possibly duplicate 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31925323/how-to-filter-out-nan-null-0-false-in-an-array-js

Comment: Where did you find the syntax `x == (a || b || c || d)` and what do you expect it to do? Why are you trying to use `splice` instead of using `filter` to create a new array?

Comment: I was trying to check if x is equal to a or b or c or d, I can tell from your comment that it's wrong syntax, would you please explain why?
I was using splice because I am new to programming so I didn't know any better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem in code:**

1. Iterate over array from last element to first element
2. [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) expects first argument as index, not the item itself
3. To check if an element is `NaN`, use [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).
4. To compare with multiple values, compare the elements individually with each item

Working code:

```js
function remove(arr) {
    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (isNaN(arr[i]) || arr[i] === 0 || arr[i] === false || arr[i] === "" || arr[i] === undefined || arr[i] === null) {

        // Which is same as
        // if (!arr[i]) {
            arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }

    console.log(arr); // Expected output [15, -22, 47]
}

remove([NaN, 0, 15, false, -22, '', undefined, 47, null]);
```

---

Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
arr = arr.filter(e => e);
```

```js
var input = [NaN, 0, 15, false, -22, '',undefined, 47, null];

var filteredArr = input.filter(e => e);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filteredArr, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Or as said by [@dandavis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2317490/dandavis) in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076104/how-to-remove-null-undefined-nan-0s-falses-and-empty-string-from-an-array-in#comment59797644_36076104)

```
arr = arr.filter(Boolean);
```

```js
var input = [NaN, 0, 15, false, -22, '',undefined, 47, null];

var filteredArr = input.filter(Boolean);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filteredArr, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Comment: look closer, it does appear that mutation is desired, so splice() might be needed still.

Comment: @dandavis Didn't understand your last, but added the code using `splice`

Comment: @Tushar Thanks alot for your answer, I have tried to run your code but only changed the iteration to count from the first element to last but it didn't work, whereas your original method worked, would you please explain why ascending looping will not work?

Comment: @MohamedHegazy Ascending order will not work because when used `splice` the array will be updated and the `index` on the next element will not work. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a26av8dn/), in the console some elements(`0` and `-22`) are missed.

Comment: @dandavis Mutation is not really desired, I was just solving this exercise so I thought splice would do the job

Answer (score 2):

This solution may not be that efficient

```
function filterArray(el) {
    return (typeof (el) === "number" && el != 0 && !isNaN(el));
}

arr = [NaN, 0, 15, false, -22, '', undefined, 47, null];
console.log(arr.filter(filterArray));
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7c5aL2ja/1/)

Comment: Won't this remove strings?

Comment: how about using truthiness?  console.log(arr.filter(function(n){return n;}))

Answer (score 2):

use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#compact).

```
console.log(_.compact(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

You refer to using `splice` so I assume you want an in-place (mutating) solution. Here's a simple, quick approach:

```
function compact(a) {
  var i = 0, j = 0;

  while (i < a.length) {
    var v = a[i++];
    if (v) a[j++] = v;
  }

  a.length = j;
}
```

In case you care (and you probably shouldn't), this is 10 times faster than a loop over `splice`. See http://jsperf.com/compacting-an-array.

If you want a solution which creates a new array, the alternatives given in other answers using `filter` are fine, but here's a basic version:

```
function compact(a) {
  var i = 0, j = 0, result = [];

  while (i < a.length) {
    var v = a[i++];
    if (v) result[j++] = v;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Mutation means you change the input. That's what `splice` does, and that's how my first sample code works. The alternative to mutation (in-place) is to create a new array with just the values you want. That's how `filter` works, and also how my second sample code works.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function bouncer(arr) {
  var newArr=arr.slice(0);
  var n=0;
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i]==false||arr[i]==null||arr[i]==0||arr[i]==""||arr[i]==undefined||Number.isNaN(arr[i])==true){
      newArr.splice(n,1);

    } else n++;
  }
  console.log(newArr);
  return newArr;
}

bouncer([null, NaN, 1, 2, undefined,0,'a']);
```

I have tried to do it with slice()... For NaN I used the function Number.isNaN() and if returns true goes on...
The input was [null, NaN, 1, 2, undefined,0,'a'] and returned [ 1, 2, 'a'] as it is expected... Hope it helped you